# iOS: buttons in tableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

Hi I am using a custom tableview cell that has an up/down button for it. What the buttons do is increase/decrease the rating of the content of the tableviewcell.

How do I write this method so that it will print out button pressed: up for cell: #17?

- (IBAction) action(id):sender;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `UIControl`. More specifically `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. Just do that in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`